# Recommending boost::variant over unions

Tags: c++, boost, unions

Are there any use cases where a union must be used and boost::variant cannot be used?

*More specifically:* **Are there any problems which unions can solve and boost::variant can't?**

As C++ standard committee recommends [using variant instead of union](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#-p4-ideally-a-program-should-be-statically-type-safe)
.

Comment: [Type-punning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_punning)? Functions which expects `union` arguments? When Boost is not available or can't be used?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Isn't type punning through unions UB in C++ as you read a field other than the one last assigned to?

Comment: It is UB, but people still use it, so compilers grudgingly allow it in some limited cases.

Comment: Unions are useful inside implementations of certain classes (e.g. string, any, function). I'd say you shouldn't use them in leaf code, but they may be an appropriate tool for library writers.

Comment: Implementing [P0083R1](http://wg21.link/P0083R1)?

Comment: Regarding type-punning, it's in C it's defined, I always mix those up. :)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Seems rather important to not mix that up. And also easy to remember. C has only PODs

Answer (score 2):

Although unions technically allow some things that variants would not, in practice those things are Undefined Behaviour.

Note that this is a lot stronger than Implementation Defined: you cannot depend on the same compiler doing the same thing twice, or a future version of the compiler doing the same thing.

In terms of portability, there would be none, because UB means "anything can happen".

> The fact that some compilers *treat* it as Implementation Defined *for now* is really just a side note in the scope of Standard C++

Variants aim to make the *discriminated union* (`tuple(union, discriminant)`) safe, a bit like array_view is designed to make `tuple(pointer, size)` safe.